# Insert a time stamp into database via ContentValues

Tags: java, android, timestamp, android-sqlite

In Android, is it possible to insert a time stamp into a database using `ContentValues`? When I try to add it using something like this:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();       
args.put(MY_DATE, my_date);
```

I get an error telling me that `my_date` needs to be a `String`. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither `Date` nor `Calendar` are valid things to put in a [`ContentValues`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html). The most efficient format, I think, is to convert the `Date` to milliseconds (`getTime()`) and store that in an `INTEGER` column.

Comment: Note though, you can't use getInt() when retrieving the data, you need to use getDouble() (on the cursor). Java-ints arn't big enough to store timestamps (this game me a major headace a while ago).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It seems that I can add the timestamp to the contentvalues as a string and that it inserts into the database as an sql timestamp, when I use mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args),  no problem.